# Rundeck SCM SSh key

Tags: ssh

Failed cloning the repository from ssh://git@xxxxx:dev/test.git: Exception caught during execution of fetch command

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8UFP.png)

Don't know why

I guess it is the ssh key configuration problem. I hope someone can give me some advice